# asp.net listview Container.DataItemIndex

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am trying to pass commandarguments like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName='<%# Eval("Section_Name")%>' CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```

but I get this error:

'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'DataItemIndex' and no extension method 'DataItemIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is the correct method to pass the commandarguments? 
This button is inside and updatepanel in the itemtemplate of a listview.

Thanks, Ali

Answer (score 8):

Thanks a lot DavidGouge and Jason Berkan. 
I made it working using

```
CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex")%>'
```

However, I think both of the suggestions should also work.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Repeater, 
you can use "*Container.ItemIndex*" to retrieve the item index.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the button is inside an update panel which is the "Container" and you're trying to get the DataItemIndex of that UpdatePanel which obviously doesn't exist.

Could you pass the "Id" of the item you'll be saving to the CommandArgument directly with Eval("WhateverId") ?

EDIT: If you really do need the DataItemIndex, this will get it for you:

```
<%# ((ListViewDataItem)Container).DataItemIndex %>
```

Comment: I would use that then as you key to what you are saving.

Comment: No but my situation requires the use of the index of the item rather than ID. How can I get that in an update panel?

Comment: You could try Container.Container.DataItemIndex

Comment: No, scratch that, that doesn't work either.  Just running an example, I'll post back if anything comes up.

Comment: Ok, give this a try:

<%# ((ListViewDataItem)Container).DataItemIndex %>

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, I've found it easiest to set the CommandArgument in the code behind.  In the ItemCreated event:

```
Dim btnSave As Button = e.Item.FindControl("btnSave")
btnSave.CommandArgument = e.Item.DataItemIndex
```

Comment: TBH, I also tend to fall back to code behind once the binding markup starts to get too complicated.