# Table ID (PrimaryKey) does not increment in a proper sequence when a new record is inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I delete a record in a table using SQL Server 2008 and its Management Studio, and then insert a new record, sequence of primary key column is not in order.

Suppose I delete Record5 with `record_id = 5`. Table is left with 4 records i.e., `Record1,Record2,Record3,Record4`.

Now when I insert a new record .. its `ID` (primary key) is automatically set to 6. I need SQL Server to set it as 5.

Because it looks weird when I display this table in a gridView in Asp.Net (c#), my table's `record_id` column sequence is something like `1, 2, 3, 17, 18, 29` etc.,

It looks very bad. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be exposing these ID values to users - if you need a number for display purposes, look into calling `ROW_NUMBER()` in your `SELECT` statement. You should treat identity values as opaque blobs that you just happen to be able to store in an `int` - you shouldn't in any way rely on their actual numeric value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Kindly help me to get out of this weird situation I am in .. your piece of advice is sure valuable but cannot be entertained at the moment. I need to get out of the situation. Please help.

Comment: I'd assume that, if record 1 was deleted, you want all existing rows shuffled up by 1 also? If so, it can't be done whilst the column is marked as an `IDENTITY` column - so *any* fix is going to require re-work somewhere - why not fix things properly?

Comment: Well, I simply don't think you are in any situation and there are any problems here. If record 5 is deleted, it stays deleted. You can't have 5 again, 6 is next. I would disagree that it looks bad.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: The original asks why identity columns are not strictly increasing.  This question asks how you can get a strictly increasing number.  How is that duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound unbelievable, but if you want an incrementing record number, SQL Server has no support for you.  A transaction that is rolled back or a server restart can leave holes in the numbers.

For a strictly increasing order, you have to roll your own implementation.  One common solution is to create a table with a list of most recently handed out numbers.  If you retrieve and increase the number in an atomic manner, that is thread-safe.  For example:

```
update  NumbersTable
set     Nr = Nr + 1
output  deleted.Nr
where   Type = 'OrderNumber'
```

Another option is to dynamically retrieve the highest order number.  With the appropriate locking hints, that can be done in a thread-safe way:

```
insert  OrdersTable
        (OrderNr, col1, col2, col3)
select  isnull((
        select  max(OrderNr) + 1
        from    OrdersTable with (tablock, holdlock)
        ), 1)
,       'value1'
,       'value2'
,       'value3'
```

If you delete a row, you'll have to implement that manually.  Say that records 1, 2 and 3 exist.  You delete record 2.  What number should the new order get?  If you say 2, remember that means order 2 is created after order 3, which would confuse a lot of people.

Comment: @ Andomar : Thats true. But how it works in MS Excel ... you delete a row .. row below it takes over its index. I think if somehow i get that implemented, it will hopefully solve my situation. (meet my requirements)

Comment: You could run a `update YourTable set NrColumn = NrColumn - 1 where NrColumn > @deletedNr` after your delete statement.  Make sure that the column in question is not used as a foreign key or relied on by any user.

Comment: @RehanMehdi Excel is not a database server with relational constraints.

Comment: @RehanMehdi - Excel shows you row numbers that it's computed for display purposes. It doesn't show you an internal pointer's value. If you're exposing an `IDENTITY` value to users, you're doing the moral equivalent of showing them an internal pointer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Haha. True that. Have started hiding it now. haha . Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Andomar Thanks for the tip. I am trying to hide the primarykey column from my users. I think better to end the story by killing the culprit.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that the IDENTITY values will not have gaps. In fact is very likely to encounter such gaps. You must design your application in a way that accommodates and expects such gaps in identity values. To display a row number in a grid the best option, by far, is to use a local client-side (ASP.Net or even browser side JS) counter. You can generate the counter server side using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) but is not the best options compared to client side.

Answer (score 2):

You need to order the diplay of your data separately from the identity column in your database. The identity column is not for "display order", in fact, it does not have any *discernable* order - it will always have holes.

Consider a table with 4 rows. Now you add 5, then delete 5 rows. The next column you enter with have its ID as 10, even though you only have 5 rows in the table.

So, stop relying on that. Instead use [`Container.ItemIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589316/asp-net-listview-container-dataitemindex) and use that to display the appropriate count of the number of rows being shown.

Comment: +1 because of the practical solution for client-side numbering

Answer (score 0):

After your Delete statement run this Queries.

```
declare @a int

set @a =(select max(identity_column_name) from table_name)
--print @a

dbcc checkident(table_name,reseed,@a)
```

Comment: @downvoter please help me in finding my mistake.

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is clearly not thread safe

Comment: @Andomar What is thread safe?

Comment: Thread safe means concurrent, i.e. that it will work if called by many  clients simultaneously.  You can simulate concurrency with while loops running in multiple tabs in SSMS.

Comment: @Luv Is there anyway I can automate this query whenever a deletion process takes place on my table?

Comment: @RehanMehdi I can't think of any automated Query.